# MSSQL - Compound WHERE clause after INNER JOIN?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query:

```
select *
from table1 d inner join table2 s on d.SOME_ID = s.SOME_ID 
where s.col1 = 'THIS' AND s.col2 = 'THAT'
```

Which is returning the same as this:

```
select *
from table1 d inner join table2 s on d.SOME_ID = s.SOME_ID 
where s.col1 = 'THIS'
```

That is, it seems to be ignoring the second part of the WHERE.

If I run this:

```
select *
from table2 s 
where s.col1 = 'THIS' AND s.col2 = 'THAT'
```

Everything works fine, and the result is filtered by both qualifications.

Am I missing something with this join thing?

EDIT:

Both tables have the 'col2', and the value is same for both (by coincidence). Interestingly, this works:

```
select *
from table1 d inner join table2 s on d.SOME_ID = s.SOME_ID 
where s.col1 = 'THIS' AND d.col2 = 'THAT'
```

It returns the single row which satisfies both qualifiers. Does this help anyone figure out what is going on?

EDIT2:

This is a shot in the dark. Since both tables contain the 'col2' column, does the join discard the table2.col2 column to produce the join? So when I filter the resulting join by a qualification on a column which is not included in the new table, they all pass?

Comment: The first part and the join filters all the rows that are needed.  Perhaps you need to add sample data and the results, so we can see what is happening.

Comment: are there in fact records where `s.col1 = 'THIS' AND s.col2 <> 'THAT'` ?

Comment: It appears that table1 doesn't have any rows that correspond to table2.col2 = 'THAT'.

Comment: @Brad - Yes, there should be 1 result, but I am getting several. (And the one result does exist..)

Comment: @Brad - Yes, there should be 1 result, but I am getting several. (And the one result does exist, and is included in the results.)

Comment: it seems this should be straightforward - maybe it would help to provide some of the actual data here..

Comment: It would definitely help - but I would get fired. Ha. I am trying to reproduce a simple example.

Comment: This is increasingly confusing...your first edit has a query that you claim works...but it is identical to your original query which you state doesn't work. I can ensure you that sql is NOT ignoring the second predicate in your where clause.

Comment: I agree - it is increasingly confusing... But the two queries are not identical. The first ends with `AND s.col2 = 'THAT'` and the second ends with `AND d.col2 = 'THAT'`. I think that should logically be identical; it seems they should result in the same thing, but they do not.